# Why do we need to install digital certificate?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, digital-certificate

The question may sound a bit stupid but I really want to know this.

When we download a file, say abc.exe, it is digitally signed with some digital certificate of some organisation. Why do we need to install that certificate? What is the use of it? What if we dont install it?

When I run certmgr.msc in my windows system, I see some certificates already installed. What do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you get signed material, you may want to verify the signature.

Digital signatures usually are created using a private key and can be verified using the associated public key.

Certificates essentially are transport containers for public keys with some extra information. Thus, to verify signatures you usually need the certificate of the signer.

You install certificates to make them known to your system (to allow for signature verification) and to tell your system to trust material signed by the associated private key.

As having to install certificates by each and every party you want to trust is too much work, certificates can have hierarchies, some root certificate may be the issuer of multiple other certificates, and by trusting that root you implicitly trust those other certificates the root issued.

For more details you may want to ask on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The RSA algorithm used for encryption is used for digital signatures.
Use of RSA for a signature is as under:

```
1. First, a message digest is calculated.
2. The private key is used to sign the digest of the message.
3. The signature is appended to the message and transmitted to the recipient.
4. The recipient calculates the digest of the received message.
5. Then, verifying the signature requires extracting the signature from the message
and using RSA on the signature with the public key.
6. If the result of the transformation and the newly calculated digest are equal, the signature is valid.
```